# Is it possible to add quick buttons in Autopilot chatbot?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

Autopilot's chatbot does seem to be not very user-friendly to expect the end-user to type out every response while engaging with the chat bot.

Any advice on improving the UX is very much appreciated. I'm a novice in this space

Much appreciated

Comment: Improve the UX of an Autopilot chatbot? You can shorten the responses to say "type 1 for this, 2 for this, and 3 for this." Autopilot provides the backend for the NLU, you can make the chatbot page look prettier with CSS if it's part of a web app?

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into this and it seems possible but I haven't gotten around to trying it yet. Basically you can:

- [Redirect](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/actions/redirect) from Autopilot to a [Twilio Serverless Function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions) which uses the Twilio Server-side Chat SDK to [create the message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/message-resource) from the bot and add the menu of appropriate responses as Message attributes (something the Chat API supports). Note, this will likely be clunky as the only way to pass the bot message and "quick" responses from the Autopilot task to the Function is as URI encoded parameters.
- For the customer side, assuming you're not building your own custom chat widget, you'll then need to extend the [Twilio Flex WebChat](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/webchat/setup) (see their [sample React project](https://github.com/twilio/flex-webchat-ui-sample)) to render the menu of responses as buttons at the end of the [MessageBubble](https://assets.flex.twilio.com/docs/releases/flex-webchat-ui/2.9.1/MessageBubble.html) component whenever a message is received with those attributes. OnClick, the buttons you render can then send those "quick" responses back as over the chat channel using [Actions.SendMessage](https://assets.flex.twilio.com/docs/releases/flex-webchat-ui/2.9.1/Actions.html). I've had good success extending this widget to add other custom functionality, but it requires a fair bit of React development and tooling knowledge.

Note I just came up with it from reading through all the documentation, Twilio might have a better suggestion. But hopefully you find this info useful, good luck.